# is there any way to extract the data values from these objects

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-functional-component

I have data like as below in image and i am trying to extract `Data` array from the json that was in below image.

[image]

Data is having key values like `condition_type` and other values also.

I can be able to get the each individual values using below code

```
const  submitcode = (data) => {
  const tasks = Object.values(data);
  console.log(tasks[0].Data[0]);
 }
 console.log(tasks[0].Data[0]);
```

Could any one please suggest is there any way to fetch `Data` array from these 6 objects using react JS.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your array in the screenshot is called `tasks`, you can use a map with object and array destructuring:

`tasks.map(({ Data: [el] }) => el);`

```js
const tasks = [{ Data: [{ a: 1, b: 2 }] }, { Data: [{ a: 3, b: 4 }] }];
console.log(tasks.map(({ Data: [el] }) => el));
```

Or also a bit hacky, using object destructiring twice also with the array, using the array index:

`tasks.map(({ Data: { 0: el } }) => el);`

```js
const tasks = [{ Data: [{ a: 1, b: 2 }] }, { Data: [{ a: 3, b: 4 }] }];
console.log(tasks.map(({ Data: { 0: el } }) => el));
```

Comment: hi many thanks for the support , can i go ahead and access the values like this `el.a`

Comment: Sure you can, you can destructure them directly in the argument too

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple snippet that returns array of `Data`'s

```js
const array = [
  {Cols: [], Data: [{condition_type: "1"}], title: "Environmental Condition"},
  {Cols: [], Data: [{condition_type: "2"}], title: "Ventilation"},
  {Cols: [], Data: [{condition_type: "3"}], title: "Thermal Comfort"},
  {Cols: [], Data: [{condition_type: "4"}], title: "Internal Loads"},
  {Cols: [], Data: [{condition_type: "5"}], title: "Exhaust"},
  {Cols: [], Data: [{condition_type: "6"}], title: "Misc"},
]

console.log(array.map(({Data: [val]})=>val))
```

or if you want to directly access the values of particular keys

```js
const array = [
  {Cols: [], Data: [{condition_type: "1"}], title: "Environmental Condition"},
  {Cols: [], Data: [{condition_type: "2"}], title: "Ventilation"},
  {Cols: [], Data: [{condition_type: "3"}], title: "Thermal Comfort"},
  {Cols: [], Data: [{condition_type: "4"}], title: "Internal Loads"},
  {Cols: [], Data: [{condition_type: "5"}], title: "Exhaust"},
  {Cols: [], Data: [{condition_type: "6"}], title: "Misc"},
]

console.log(array.map(({Data: [{condition_type}]})=>condition_type))
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions and i need to assign values to some input variables, can i go ahead add like this `val.condition_type`

Answer (score 0):

you can map the parent (tasks array) and get the child (data array)

```
const result = tasks.map(s => s.Data[0]);
//result contains array of Data objects
```